# How do I manually install the package selections presented in tasksel?

Tags: server, tasksel

If you forgot to select some software at the "Software Selection" screen on a fresh install, what are the commands to install them after the fact.  I know you can install them manually at anytime after everything is said and done, but what are the commands to install just as if you [*]starred them on that screen.

For instance:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

will install the LAMP Server.  What are the commands for the DNS Server, Mail Server and Tomcat Java server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after the installer you can use `tasksel` to install tasks, it just needs installing:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

If you're just after a list of available tasks, `tasksel` is still the *easiest* way to achieve this. Install it and run `tasksel --list-task` and you get a nice list of the available tasks, their install status and a description.

And if you need a trimmed list, something like this should do:

```
tasksel --list-task | awk '{ print $2 }'
```