# How do I rerun Ubuntu Software Selection after installation is complete

Tags: server

I installed Ubuntu from the minimal CD (mini.iso).
During the install, I was presented this feature ("Software Selection"):

[image: Software Selection Screen]

How do I launch it after install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I manually install the package selections presented in tasksel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/114912)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get that screen by running: `sudo tasksel`

More information here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel

Comment: Right! If I remember correctly, I was also presented a screen to automatically install all updates, only security updates and do nothing. Can you also tell me how to bring up this screen?

Comment: Please ask that as a new question!