# Ubuntu server-desktop -hybrid installation

Tags: server

Sounds probably a bit silly to some to combine desktop and server, but that surely is what is most suitable in this case.. So:

Is there easy solution for installing both, the server and desktop packages (probably Gnome and/or something lighter) in same installer?

I mean, can you configure installer somehow to install both of them on same run or do I really need to install other one afterwards?

Or ultimately, is there already that kind of hybrid -installation media?
Maybe there's netinstall-version that could be configured to do that all?

We are planning to set up small PC (USFF / SFF) as a home server that would be running UniFi controller, Minecraft server, IRC, act as fileserver, poll some timetables that could be easily fetched from there... But also possibly it would be connected to monitor other side of the room so it could be used as media-PC too (If it's possible..).

I'm not afraid of using time or efforts or cli, but making things optimal is always a goal for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu server install asks you to select the software to install. You could select whichever server software and desktop you wanted at that stage and both will be installed. See, for example, this question and the screenshot in it: [How do I rerun Ubuntu Software Selection after installation is complete](https://askubuntu.com/q/243950/)

[image]